# GetProcAddress fails for LoadIconWithScaleDown on Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

I'm using the following code to dynamically link to the [LoadIconWithScaleDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, for my code to be able to run on Windows XP:

```
HRESULT (WINAPI *pfnLoadIconWithScaleDown)(HINSTANCE, PCWSTR, int, int, HICON *);

HMODULE hComCtrl32 = LoadLibrary(_T("Comctl32.dll"));
if(hComCtrl32)
{
    (FARPROC&)pfnLoadIconWithScaleDown = GetProcAddress(hComCtrl32, "LoadIconWithScaleDownW");
}
```

I try this code on Windows 7, but the 'pfnLoadIconWithScaleDown' is always NULL. Why?

Comment: If you run `dumpbin /exports` on the DLL, is the symbol present?

Answer (score 3):

There is no ASCII (`A`) and UNICODE (`W`) versions of [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775703%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so change the `GetProcAddress()` invocation to:

```
pfnLoadIconWithScaleDown = GetProcAddress(hComCtrl32, "LoadIconWithScaleDown");
```

Comment: A proper side-by-side manifest is required as well so the correct version of comctl32.dll gets loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you give me more details about this side-by-side manifest, because I get NULL for what hmjd suggested as well...

Comment: Migration requirements section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531404.aspx

Comment: comctl32 v6 manifest. There are millions of articles on internet. No need to do it all again here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: OK, I realized what I was doing wrong. I read LoadLibrary security note and that they recommend always using a full path to the dll, instead of just doing LoadLibrary(L"Comctl32.dll"); So providing a full path to it would not work with the comctrl32 manifest requirement.

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. You are meant to load `comctl32.dll` using just the name. Don't include the path. Fix your manifest.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Wrong? Just hypothetically what if someone puts a malicious file named comctl32.dll in the folder with my app and adds LoadIconWithScaleDown export to it that say, infects my browser with popups instead?

Comment: Yep, wrong. Take a look at any mainstream program and look at how it imports system DLLs. What you describe is not a security hole. The breach was when you let in the thing that can write DLLs wherever it pleases. Anyway, I don't really mind if you do it your way. You don't have to take my advice.